# what is maximum limit of append text jQuery + phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making one application in phonegap using jQuery mobile where I display live streaming I am getting around six word per second.

In my success method I just display on my div using append method. My problem is that after 15 or 20 minutes in iPad My application behaves unresponsively and look link hangs deadlock then after few milliseconds if start displaying but it again hangs after few seconds.

Can you suggest how to remove this bug ?

I will give you example like that

```
<div id="realTimeContents" class ="left realtimeContend_h" style="width:100%"> 
</div>

setInterval(function () {
    $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div")
}, 10);
```

Thanks

Comment: yes ..in android it will come after 15 minumtes in ipad os 7 it will come 20 min..data is coming around 6 or 7 word per second or more words

Comment: This doesn't sound like a bug to me.  You want to add 6 words per second and are surprised that it hangs sometimes after 15-20 minutes?  I'm surprised it lasts as long as that.  What are you actually trying to do this for?

Comment: Some time it is showing white space then text after few seconds it fill the space

Comment: Please explain the purpose of what you're trying to do, because at the moment it doesn't make sense and sounds like you're purposely breaking the browser.

Comment: sorry 6 words per 10 milliseconds

Comment: I will explain more I done socket programming in phonegap using objective c plugin i show data in my screen JS part , where success method is present .i only append the result parameter which is success method

Comment: As the data is coming quickly in starting every thing is work fine .but after 15 min it display some white space then after text (after few seconds it fill the white space)

Comment: You're simply overflowing the browser with too much data.  I'd strongly suggest only allowing a certain amount of data in the div, so when you add some to the bottom you remove some from the top.  It will fix the problem, for sure.  Also, 10ms is faster than most browsers will be able to render the changes, so you might want to slow that down a bit, maybe to 100ms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44804/discussion-between-rohit-and-archer)